# Why is "s.d IS NULL" being added to my where clause using DQL in Doctrine 1.1.2 (USING leftJoin)?

Tags: mysql, doctrine, null, left-join, doctrine-query

I am using a MySQL database and Doctrine 1.1.2.

I am trying to write a query with a leftJoin and I am trying to understand the result as it has given me problems multiple times.  After I have run a few different tests, it seems almost intermittent, which I don't believe it can be.

Below, I will paste in both the DQL to create the queries, and the output from them. These four are examples I created while trying to understand why sometiems the "s.id IS NULL" is added, and why sometimes the "s.id IN ('184158')".  I would be fine if neither were ever added, but can someone explain to me why it is there, and maybe how I can tell DQL that I don't want it?

From some of the research I have done, I gather that it may be part of a bug fix (#1868) regarding if this query contains a subquery.  But, as this has no subquery, I don't know how to push forward on testing that issue for sure.

Here is the code from bug fix #1868 in doctrine/lib/Doctrine/Query.php

```
// FIX #1868: If not ID under MySQL is found to be restricted, restrict pk column for null  
//            (which will lead to a return of 0 items)  
$limitSubquerySql = $this->_conn->quoteIdentifier($field)  
    . (( ! empty($subquery)) ? ' IN (' . $subquery . ')' : ' IS NULL')  
    . ((count($this->_sqlParts['where']) > 0) ? ' AND ' : '');
```

Please and thank you.

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('s.id, p.id')  
    ->from('Submission s')  
    ->leftjoin('s.Products p ON s.product_id = p.id')  
    ->where('s.id = ?',$id)  
    ->limit(1);  
echo $query->getSqlQuery() . '< br />';  

$query = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('s.id, p.id, p.field1')  
    ->from('Submission s')  
    ->leftjoin('s.Products p ON s.product_id = p.id')  
    ->where('s.id = ?',$id)  
    ->limit(1);  
echo $query->getSqlQuery() . '< br />';  

$query = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('s.id, p.id, p.field1, p.field2')  
    ->from('Submission s')  
    ->leftjoin('s.Products p ON s.product_id = p.id')  
    ->where('s.id = ?',$id)  
    ->limit(1);  
echo $query->getSqlQuery() . '< br />';  

$query = Doctrine_Query::create()  
    ->select('s.id, p.id, p.field1, p.field2, p.field3')  
    ->from('Submission s')  
    ->leftjoin('s.Products p ON s.product_id = p.id')  
    ->where('s.id = ?',$id)  
    ->limit(1);  
echo $query->getSqlQuery() . '< br />';    

**-- OUTPUT --**  
**-- $id = 184158**  

SELECT s.id AS s__id, p.id AS p__id  
FROM submission s   
LEFT JOIN products p   
ON (s.prodid = p.id)   
WHERE **s.id IS NULL** AND (s.id = 184158) **<-- Notice the s.id IS NULL**  

SELECT s.id AS s__id, p.id AS p__id, p.field1 AS p__field1   
FROM submission s   
LEFT JOIN products p   
ON (s.prodid = p.id)   
WHERE **s.id IN ('184158')** AND (s.id = 184158) **<-- Notice the s.id IN ('184158')**  

SELECT s.id AS s__id, p.id AS p__id, p.field1 AS p__field1, p.field2 AS p__field2   
FROM submission s   
LEFT JOIN products p   
ON (s.prodid = p.id)   
WHERE **s.id IS NULL** AND (s.id = 184158) **<-- Notice the s.id IS NULL**  

SELECT s.id AS s__id, p.id AS p__id, p.field1 AS p__field1, p.field2 AS p__field2, p.field3 AS p__field3   
FROM submission s   
LEFT JOIN products p   
ON (s.prodid = p.id)   
WHERE **s.id IN ('184158')** AND (s.id = 184158) **<-- Notice the s.id IN ('184158')**
```

Comment: Not sure if this could be the cause of anything but maybe try dropping the explicit column on which your left-joining: ->leftJoin('s. Products p') ... Doctrine does over-thinking sometimes. There's always Doctrine RawSQL to bypass these strange cases as well.

Comment: A note, I have noticed that when I remove the limit statement, it no longer adds the s.id IN () not the s.id IS NULL. I will research about this topic. Thank you Tom, that did not change the outcome.

Comment: I'm also seeing this, will do a bit of digging in Doctrine source later. Frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because of several reasons:

1) Doctrine deals with Objects not "rows", so when you add a Join it will immediately need more than a simple limit Say, you want a single (fetchOne) object of a table with a one-to-many relationship, these relations add to the row count in SQL so Doctrine does it in 2 stages.

```
table1.id table2.id
1,11
1,12
2,11
2,13
2,22
3,33
```

Assuming you asked for `fetchOne` then it will get 2 rows, but 1 object will be hydrated (for the "id=1" rows)

2) If your query finds nothing then the DQL will know nothing will match so it adds `id = NULL`, or if it finds something it adds `IN (id-that-is-first)`

I had the same issue, leading me here, and it turned out the query was just not returning anything. Hope this helps.